# how to add transition my slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want add effect to my slider but I don't know how to this kind of situation?

So when click preview or next button, change slider with effect
I use The transition Property CSS code but not working!

if possible for you,Please help correct my code, Thanks!

this is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="shop-slider fade">
    </div>

    <div class="shop-slider fade">
    </div>

    <div class="shop-slider fade">
    </div>

    <div class="shop-slider fade">
    </div>

    <a class="prev-shop-slide" onclick="plusShopSlides(-1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left"></i></a>
    <a class="next-shop-slide" onclick="plusShopSlides(1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

and this is JavaScript code:

```
  var slideNum = 1;
        showShopSlides(slideNum);

        function plusShopSlides(n) {
            showShopSlides(slideNum += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
            showShopSlides(slideNum = n);
        }

        function showShopSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("shop-slider");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {slideNum = 1}
            if (n < 1) {slideNum = slides.length}
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideNum-1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideNum-1].className += " active";
        }
```

Here is my css:

```
.shop-slider-container{
     width: 600px;
     height: 350px;
     background: #fff;
    position: relative;



 }
.shop-slider {
    display: none;
    font-family: iransans;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;

}
.prev-shop-slide, .next-shop-slide {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    color: #14b8c2;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.next-shop-slide {

    margin-right: 10px;

}
.prev-shop-slide {
   margin-right: 40px;

}
.prev-shop-slide:hover, .next-shop-slide:hover {
  color: #000;
}.fade {

}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {


}

@keyframes fade {


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the additional effects in jQuery UI:[slide-effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)

**example**

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

use jquery in this case, good luck !!

Comment: I dont add library to my code!is there a better method?

Comment: on this case you code is more clean more easy, exist soo many method for create a slider this is a simple example

Comment: or a other way is use a Bootstrap is soo very good https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators

Comment: I want edit this code! i add fade css code but i cant use @keyframes